# Understanding why 2*density of a isolated gas equals half the initial temperature

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas, volume, inert-gases

A vertical cylinder of cross-sectional area 0.050 m2 is fitted with a tight-fitting, frictionless piston of mass 5.00 kg. The cylinder contains 3.00 mol of an ideal gas at 227°C.

At what temperature would the density of the enclosed gas be double its 227°C value?
I understand why 2*density = half of the Volume, but I've been told that this also equals half the initial Temperature.

I would have thought the compression by half the volume would cause the temperature to be doubled.

Comment: PV = nRT holds for ideal gases.

Answer (score 1):

For an ideal gas we have $PV=nRT$, where $P$ is the pressure, $V$ is the volume, $n$ the number of moles, $R$ the Regnault constant and $T$ the temperature. This can be rewritten as

$
P\frac{V}{M}=n\frac{R}{M} T$ then

$\frac{P}{\rho} = n{R_s} T
$

where we introduced $R_s=\frac{R}{M}$ called specific Regnault constant, dependent on the nature of the material, and the density, $\rho = \frac{M}{V}$.

We thus have

$
T = \frac{1}{n R_s}\frac{P}{\rho}
$

Now you look for a new density, two times the old one, $\rho' = 2\rho$. If we don't change the pressure,

$
{T'} = \frac{1}{n R_s}\frac{P}{\rho'} $ then

${T'} = \frac{1}{n R_s}\frac{P}{2\rho}$ then

${2T'} = \frac{1}{n R_s}\frac{P}{\rho}
$

where in the second step we replaced $\rho' = 2\rho$.
In the last step we recognize the old temperature $T$

$
{2T'} = \frac{1}{n R_s}\frac{P}{\rho} = T
$

Which proves that to double the density, you need to divide the old temperature by a factor of 2.

$T' = \frac T 2$.

In your case

$T' = \frac {(227+273)} 2 K= 250K = -23 C$.